# ios swift, How to convert 'object to nsdata'

Tags: ios, swift, object, serialization, nsdata

I want to define a c ++ structure as swift code and serialize and deserialize it to write to socket.

```
class PacketHeader: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var ver: UInt8 = 0
    var len: UInt32 = 0

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        ??
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        ??
    }
}
```

I can not find a function to decode and encode uint8, uint32.

Comment: why don't you use it as object? I mean say convert it into NSNumber, check it. there is option also  open func decodeInt32(forKey key: String) -> Int32

    open func decodeInt64(forKey key: String) -> Int64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 8 (Swift 3) Playground:

```
class PacketHeader: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var ver: UInt8 = 0
    var len: UInt32 = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        if let ver = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "ver") as? NSNumber {
            self.ver = ver.uint8Value
        }

        if let len = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "len") as? NSNumber {
            self.len = len.uint32Value
        }

    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(NSNumber(value: ver), forKey: "ver")
        aCoder.encode(NSNumber(value: len), forKey: "len")
    }

}

let data = PacketHeader()
data.ver = 10
data.len = 8

let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)
let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: savedData) as? PacketHeader
obj?.ver
obj?.len
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do if you don't want to convert to `NSNumber`, though I suspect that this must be a duplicate question:

```
class PacketHeader: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var ver: UInt8 = 0
    var len: UInt32 = 0

    init(ver: UInt8, len: UInt32) {
        self.ver = ver
        self.len = len
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.ver = UInt8(aDecoder.decodeCInt(forKey: "ver"))
        self.len = UInt32(aDecoder.decodeCInt(forKey: "len"))
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeCInt(Int32(self.ver), forKey: "ver")
        aCoder.encodeCInt(Int32(self.len), forKey: "len")
    }
}

let x = PacketHeader(ver: 75, len: 123)
let e = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: x)
if let y = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: e) as? PacketHeader {
    print("\(y.ver), \(y.len)") // 75, 123
} else {
    print("URK???")
}
```